# Read values from several Text Boxes and alert values via jQuery

Tags: jquery

When I click on "btnButton" I need all values from input fileds(Value One,Value Two, Value Three and Value four) to be looped and represented via alert function in jquery.

```html
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4" id="MainContent_gvAllValues" style="color:#333333;border-collapse:collapse;">
  <tr style="color:White;background-color:#507CD1;font-weight:bold;">
    <th scope="col" vAllValues</th>
  </tr>
  <tr style="background-color:#EFF3FB;">
    <td>
      <input name="ctl00$MainContent$gvAllValues$ctl02vAllValues" type="text" value="RR Value One" id="MainContent_gvAllValues_0" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="background-color:White;">
    <td>
      <input name="ctl00$MainContent$gvAllValues$ctl03vAllValues" type="text" value="RR Value Two" id="MainContent_gvAllValues_1" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="background-color:#EFF3FB;">
    <td>
      <input name="ctl00$MainContent$gvAllValues$ctl04vAllValues" type="text" value="RR Value Three" id="MainContent_gvAllValues_2" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="background-color:White;">
    <td>
      <input name="ctl00$MainContent$gvAllValues$ctl05vAllValues" type="text" value="RR Value Four" id="MainContent_gvAllValues_3" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<br />
<br />
<br />
<input type="submit" name="ctl00$MainContent$btnButton" value="Button" id="MainContent_btnButton" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `$.each` function on all the input type of textboxes available in your form and alert them like this

```js
$('#MainContent_btnButton').click(function(){
var alltextBoxMessages = "";
  $('input[type=text]').each(function(){
  alltextBoxMessages = alltextBoxMessages + " " + $(this).val();   
  }); 
   alert(alltextBoxMessages);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4" id="MainContent_gvAllValues" style="color:#333333;border-collapse:collapse;">
            <tr style="color:White;background-color:#507CD1;font-weight:bold;">
                <th scope="col"vAllValues</th>
            </tr><tr style="background-color:#EFF3FB;">
                <td>

                            <input name="ctl00$MainContent$gvAllValues$ctl02vAllValues" type="text" value="RR Value One" id="MainContent_gvAllValues_0" />

                        </td>
            </tr><tr style="background-color:White;">
                <td>

                            <input name="ctl00$MainContent$gvAllValues$ctl03vAllValues" type="text" value="RR Value Two" id="MainContent_gvAllValues_1" />

                        </td>
            </tr><tr style="background-color:#EFF3FB;">
                <td>

                            <input name="ctl00$MainContent$gvAllValues$ctl04vAllValues" type="text" value="RR Value Three" id="MainContent_gvAllValues_2" />

                        </td>
            </tr><tr style="background-color:White;">
                <td>

                            <input name="ctl00$MainContent$gvAllValues$ctl05vAllValues" type="text" value="RR Value Four" id="MainContent_gvAllValues_3" />

                        </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
            <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <input type="submit" name="ctl00$MainContent$btnButton" value="Button" id="MainContent_btnButton" />
```

Comment: Thank you Monicka ! This works perfectly. 
I have another small question. Is there any way that those values can be shown all in the same time in one alert message ? 
In this version of code the are 4 different alert windows shown from start to finish.
Thank you in advance !

Comment: Sure, I have modified the code, to show all the text box values in a single alert. Please mark my response as answered as it has solved your issue

Answer (score 0):

```
Try This ,Its Working fine.
html:
<input type="submit" name="ctl00$MainContent$btnButton" value="Button" id="MainContent_btnButton" onclick="ClickFunction()" />


//javascript
   function ClickFunction() {
            for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                alert($('#MainContent_gvAllValues_'+i+'').val());
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, add function to your submit button

```
<input type="submit" name="ctl00$MainContent$btnButton" value="Button" id="MainContent_btnButton" onclick="func()" />
```

the create a JS and  loop the variables

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        function func() {
            for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                alert(document.getElementById('MainContent_gvAllValues_'+i).value);
            }

        }
    </script>
```